# Are there reliable Linux ChaCha20-Poly1305 implementations available for stream encryption?

Tags: encryption, chacha20

I'd currently encrypt a stream by piping it through the following command:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pass file:/[keyfile path]
```

Is there a reliable implementation of [ChaCha20-Poly1305](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7539) that I can use instead?

Comment: Either your version of OpenSSL is too old or you did not look hard enough. `openssl enc --ciphers` offers me also chacha20. It's at least there since OpenSSL 1.1.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last I read `openssl enc` specifically avoids providing a `MAC` or `AEAD` cipher because [they're worried about providing a footgun](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/471#issuecomment-356414321) to inexperienced users. And rightfully so, if you were to pipe the decryption output somewhere that processes it (rather than a temporary file) you would be processing unauthenticated data, only verifying the authenticity after the damage has been done.

While it's possible to safely stream encryption, it is definitely *not* safe to stream *decryption*, so I expect you are unlikely to find such an implementation. If you do, expect it to be insecure.

Comment: Please could you comment on the effectiveness of using aes-256-gcm provided by openssl - specifically whether you would consider that flawed as a means of providing data integrity?

Comment: @knaccc While openssl 1.0.2g lists `-aes-256-gcm` as a cipher, trying to use it causes an error: `AEAD ciphers not supported by the enc utility`. openssl 1.1.0h (and probably earlier, that's just the version I have on hand) no longer lists any gcm ciphers with `openssl enc --ciphers`.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald Even worse, some of the earlier versions were broken and encrypted files using GCM could later not be decrypted.